# How to group by specific attributes and orderby another one?

Tags: c#, linq, select, group-by, sql-order-by

I want to make a query that will get me distinct pairs of  postGroup and ApplicationUserId which are attributes of the Post table.
I also want to order the selected posts by their PostDate which is also an attribute in this Table and I use the where condition to select only posts of users or sites i followed, or mine.

I am unable to achieve this but this is what i tried:

```
 var posts = (from m in context.Posts
                     orderby m.PostDate descending
                     where ((context.FollowedUsers
        .FirstOrDefault(n => n.FollowerId == Id && n.ApplicationUserId == m.ApplicationUserId)) != null
        || (context.FollowedSites.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ApplicationUserId == Id && n.SiteId == m.SiteId) != null)
        || m.ApplicationUserId == Id)
                     group m by new { m.PostGroup, m.ApplicationUserId } into g
                     select new { g.Key.ApplicationUserId, g.Key.PostGroup } ).Skip(skip).Take(nOfPosts).ToList();
```

This will generate the distinct pairs without ordering.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you post some example data along with the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grouping removes the ordering. Each group can contain any `PostDate` and it's impossible to tell at that point by which date the groups should be ordered.

You have to move the ordering past the grouping:

```cs
var posts = (from m in context.Posts
             where context.FollowedUsers.Any(n => n.FollowerId == Id && n.ApplicationUserId == m.ApplicationUserId)
                || context.FollowedSites.Any(n => n.ApplicationUserId == Id && n.SiteId == m.SiteId)
                || m.ApplicationUserId == Id
            group m by new { m.PostGroup, m.ApplicationUserId } into g
            orderby g.Max(m => m.PostDate) descending
            select new 
            {
                g.Key.ApplicationUserId, 
                g.Key.PostGroup 
            }).Skip(skip).Take(nOfPosts).ToList();
```

Side note: I also modified some predicates into `Any`.

Comment: Thank you! Highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Im not sure what do you want to achieve. Your query looks ok. U are sure result is wrong? 
After order by PostDate, result looks like e.g.

```
Data        UserId      PostGroup
----------- ----------- -----------
3           10          1
2           20          2
2           10          2
1           20          2
```

After Group by UserId and PostGroup result should looks like

```
UserId      PostGroup
----------- -----------
10          1
20          2
10          2
```

And your  query produce that result.
I rewrite your query, u can check result with this:

```
var posts = context.Posts.OrderByDescending(p => p.PostDate)
    .Where(m => context.FollowedUsers.FirstOrDefault(n => n.FollowerId == Id && n.ApplicationUserId == m.ApplicationUserId)) != null || (context.FollowedSites.FirstOrDefault(n => n.ApplicationUserId == Id && n.SiteId == m.SiteId) != null) || m.ApplicationUserId == Id)
    .GroupBy(group => new { group.PostGroup, group.ApplicationUserId })
    .Select(x => new { x.Key.ApplicationUserId, x.Key.PostGroup })
    .Skip(skip).Take(nOfPosts).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, this query doesn't preserve the ordering. appreciated.